# My innerHTML command isn't changing anything and i can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, html, function

The code is as follows:

```
    <div id="js"><button onclick="document.getElementById('js').innerHTML=('<form>
    <input type=text name=tick1></input>
    <input type=text name=tick2></input>
    <input type=text name=tick3></input>
    <input type=submit></input>
</form>')">Kaarten bestellen</button>

</div>
```

I really can't see why it's not working. When i put the form as actual html outside of the script it works fine, and when i use something more like .innerHTML('test') it works just fine. I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `\` ([see Multiline String Variables in JavaScript](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/multiline-string-variables-in-javascript/)) to end of every line in your multiline string:

```
<div id="js"><button onclick="document.getElementById('js').innerHTML=('<form>\
    <input type=text name=tick1></input>\
    <input type=text name=tick2></input>\
    <input type=text name=tick3></input>\
    <input type=submit></input>\
</form>')">Kaarten bestellen</button>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5tuqt1L/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's going to be very useful in the future!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine. You just cannot use linebreaks in this js code. you could use + operator to connect strings.

```
document.getElementById('js').innerHTML=('<form>'
+'<input type=text name=tick1></input><input type=text name=tick2>'
+'</input><input type=text name=tick3></input><input type=submit>'
+'</input></form>');
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnznfr2h/)

Answer (score 1):

The string literal is not closed, since its multiple rows...why don't you just hide it?

```html
<div id="js">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').style.display='block';this.style.display='none';">
        Kaarten bestellen
    </button>
    <form id="myForm" style="display:none">
        <input type=text name=tick1></input>
        <input type=text name=tick2></input>
        <input type=text name=tick3></input>
        <input type=submit></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `innerHTML` is a property, not a method, so you just assign a value to it like so

```
document.getElementById('js').innerHTML = "Hello, World.";
```

[innerHTML Explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Your HTML has invalid syntax:

```
<form>
<input type=text name=tick1></input>
<input type=text name=tick2></input>
<input type=text name=tick3></input>
<input type=submit></input>
</form>
```

Your `type` and `name` attribute values need to be wrapped in double quotes `"`. The `input` element doesn't require contents either so you can make it self closing. Check this:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="tick1" />
<input type="text" name="tick2" />
<input type="text" name="tick3" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript strings are not multiline. So you need to escape line breaks, like so:

```
<form>\
<input type="text" name="tick1" />\
<input type="text" name="tick2" />\
<input type="text" name="tick3" />\
<input type="submit" />\
</form>
```

[Explaination on Multi-Line Javascript Strings](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings)

Answer (score 1):

this is also an  answer if i understand your problem in right way.

```
<div id="js"><button onclick="document.getElementById('js').innerHTML='<form>'
    +'<input type=\'text\' name=\'tick1\'></input>'
    +'<input type=\'text\' name=\'tick2\'></input>'
    +'<input type=\'text\' name=\'tick3\'></input>'
    +'<input type=\'submit\'></input>'
 +'</form>'">Kaarten bestellen</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div id="js"><button onclick="document.getElementById('js').innerHTML='<form><input type=text name=tick1></input><input type=text name=tick2></input><input type=text name=tick3></input><input type=submit></input></form>'">Kaarten bestellen</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="js"><button onclick="document.getElementById('js').innerHTML='\
    <form>\
        <input type=text name=tick1></input>\
        <input type=text name=tick2></input>\
        <input type=text name=tick3></input>\
        <input type=submit></input>\
    </form>\
'">Kaarten bestellen</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is cause because the content to be displayed is spanning several lines without being concatenated properly. I have reworked it as follows;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadForm(){
            var formContent ="<form>"
                            +"<input type='text' name='tick1'></input>"
                            +"<input type='text' name='tick2'></input>"
                            +"<input type='text' name='tick3'></input>"
                            +"<input type='submit'></input>"
                            +"</form>";
            document.getElementById('js').innerHTML =(formContent);
        }
    </script>

    <div id="js">
        <button onclick="loadForm()">Kaarten bestellen</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think this also makes the code cleaner.